# iterating through a file with millions of lines

Tags: python, loops, large-files

I am trying to iterate through a file with millions of lines containg some data and I am retrieving it. Unfortunately this is going very slow and I was wondering how I could make it more efficient.
At the moment I am loading two files and I am iterating by each line.

The code:

```
# Retrieve session data
UBList = array([line.split('\t') for line in source])
SID = set(UBList[:,1])
n_unique_sessions = len(Counter(UBList[:,1]))
source.close()
sessions = {}
session_info = {}
purchases = array([line.split('\t') for line in open('Data/order_overview.txt', 'r').readlines()])

for sid in SID:
    print sid
    s = [line for line in UBList if line[1]==sid]
    uline = [line for line in s if line[3]=='17']
    tline = [line[2] for line in s]
    t_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
    s_start = datetime.strptime(tline[0], t_format)
    s_end = datetime.strptime(tline[-1], t_format)
    s_length = (s_end - s_start).total_seconds()
    d_time = [line[2] for line in s if line[3]=='4']
    if len(uline) > 0: 
        uid = uline[0][12]
    else: 
        uid = 'NotFound'
    num_queries = len([line for line in s if line[3]=='27'])
    num_purchases = nonzero(purchases[:,0]==sid)[0].shape[0]
    sessions.update({sid: (uid, num_queries, num_purchases, s)})
    f = open('Results/' + sid + '_' + uid + '_' + str(num_queries) + '_' + str(num_purchases) + '_' + str(s_length) + '.txt', 'w')
    f.writelines(['\t'.join(line) for line in s])
    f.close()
```

Would something like this speed things up?

```
somevar = dict([sid, [] for sid in SID])
for line in UBList:
sid = line[1]
dSID[sid].append('\t'.join(line))
```

Also is it possible to get the next line after a certain criteria is met? For example I find a line get its value with the next and do a calculation. And add the results if the line with the criteria was found multiple times.

Comment: I think this question suits better in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah, I'd try cache UBList as what you say, and use csvreader (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read the file, indicating that your separator is a tab (\t) The example is a bit complex for me to understand what's happening there and provide a more definite answer.

Comment: I think that ``array`` is the function in the ``numpy`` module. Could you describe the structure of the lines in ``source`` ? I think there are several errors in your use of numpy objects

Comment: @eyquem The line in the source are tab seperated strings on each line. so something like abc [tab] def [tab] 123 [tab] 456 and so on for each line.   BorrajaX: so instead of storing UBList read it line for line? I am a bit confised should I store data in a csv file? My current data is in a txt file.

Comment: Is ``array`` the method ``numpy.array`` or not ? If not, I wouldn't understand the writing ``UBList[:,1]`` with a comma in it

Comment: @eyquem it is a numpy.array.

Answer (score 0):

If `source` is your file object, don't read it all to memory beforehand. You can process it and read at the same time, and Python is clever enough to process data while waiting for next chunk to be read. To achieve that, use list generators, not list comprehensions.

You create a lot of arrays you don't actually need, like `s`. Replace them with generators and get a speedup. Creating standard Python array is a heavy operation, and if it's bigger than a 4kB, generators should be better.

Comment: So instead of storing I should read it and process it? With something like while open(source) do .....